# Non-modular coverings of modular curve

Tags: modular-arithmetic, elliptic-curves, riemann-surfaces, modular-forms, modular-function

Let $Y$ be a Riemann surface, and
$$T=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k y^k \in K(Y)[y]$$
be a polynomial in $y$ of degree $n$ over the field $K(Y)$ of meromorphic functions on $Y$. If we denote by $O$ the discrete subset of $Y$ containing all poles of the coefficients $a_k$ and the zeros of the discriminant of $T$, then $T=0$ defines an $n$-fold ramified covering $\pi: M\to Y$ together with a meromorphic function $y$ on $M$, such that for all $x_0=Y\backslash 0$ the set of roots of $T_{x_0}$ coincides with the set of values of $y$ on the preimage $\pi^{-1}(x_0)$.

Let now $Y=X(1)$ be the modular curve for $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$, which is a compactification of its fundamental domain $SL(2,\mathbb Z)\backslash \mathbb H$. In case the polynomial $T$ is such that its roots are modular functions for a congruence subgroup $\Gamma\subset SL(2,\mathbb Z)$ of index $[SL(2,\mathbb Z):\Gamma]=n$, then $T=0$ defines an $n$-fold covering over $X(1)$, which is precisely the modular curve of $\Gamma$ (a compactification of $\Gamma\backslash SL(2,\mathbb Z)$).

In case the polynomial $T$ is not of such a form,  $T=0$ defines a Riemann surface $M$ that is not a modular curve, and any root $y$ of $T=0$ is not a modular function for a congruence subgroup. I am wondering if nevertheless statements can be made about $y$, for instance:

- Is there a domain $D\subset\mathbb H$ such that $y:D\to P^1(\mathbb C)$ is an isomorphism ($y$ is a Hauptmodul and $D$ is a fundamental domain for $y$)? Can $M$ be "unfolded" on the upper half-plane $\mathbb H$, with maps $\alpha_j\in SL(2,\mathbb Z)$ such that $D=\bigcup_{j=1}^n \alpha_j\mathcal F$ where $\mathcal F$ is a fundamental domain for $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$?
- Is $y$ automorphic on $M$?

Many thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: For $Y=X(1)$ then $K(Y)=K(j(z))$ so that's a bit easier. You can see locally if $y$ is meromorphic on $\Bbb{H}$, for example $j(z)^{1/13}$ is not because it has a branch point at $e^{2i\pi/3}$. But $(j(z)-1728)^{1/2}$ is meromorphic on $\Bbb{H}$, because the only zeros of $j(z)-1728$ are double. If $y$ is meromorphic then it will be invariant under a finite index subgroup $G$ of $SL_2(Z)$, some of them are not congruence subgroups ([KConrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/SL(2,Z).pdf) p.10) And $y$ doesn't have to be injective on the fundamental domain of $\Bbb{H}/G$

Comment: Yes I think if $y$ is meromorphic on $\Bbb{H}$ then $M = \Bbb{H}^*/G$ (the projective smooth curve where $y$ lies), because the $y \circ \gamma,\gamma\in SL_2(\Bbb{Z})$ are $K(j)$ conjugates to $y$ and $SL_2(\Bbb{Z})/(\bigcap \gamma G\gamma^{-1})$ will be the Galois group of $K(j, \{ y \circ \gamma,\gamma\in SL_2(\Bbb{Z})\})/K(j)$

Comment: Thank you, I agree with the first message. How does one determine in general whether a root is meromorphic on $\mathbb H$? Consider for instance the polynomial $T(y)=y^n-j$. If $n=3$, then $y$ is a Hauptmodul for the Atkin-Lehner congruence subgroup $\Gamma_0(3|3)$. But if $n\not\in \{1,3\}$ then $y$ is not meromorphic and thus not modular on $\mathbb H$. How can this be read off from the discriminant $\Delta_yT(y)=j^{n-1}$? And could you elaborate on the second comment?

Comment: Locally at $a$, $y$ will be in $R(j^{1/e})$ where $R$ is the field of all meromorphic functions around $a$, and $e$ is the ramification index. Once we know the Galois group of the normal closure then we know all the intermediate fields: $K(j,y)=K(M)$ is the subfield fixed by $G$.